# add multiple val in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want do to click and display in textarea.

The problem is once I click the fullname, the fullname will display in textarea;

and then click ic, the ic will display in textarea but replaced the fullname.

What should I do to make fullname,ic,hp not replace each other? I want to let user click by the variable they want, therefore I didnt do 3 variables insert in one click.

```
<span onclick=\"insert_user_eh_name('".$row['fullname']."','','');\">".$row['fullname']."</span>
<span onclick=\"insert_user_eh_name('','".$row['ic']."','');\">".$row['ic']."</span>
<span onclick=\"insert_user_eh_name('','','".$row['hp']."');\">".$row['hp']."</span>

  function insert_user_eh_name(fullname,ic,phone){
  jQuery("#text-area").val(fullname+ ic +phone);}
```

Comment: you could change `.val` to `.append` but id want to get rid of all the inline js. thats horrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you're using jQuery, here's the solution you would want:

```
var insertIntoTextArea = null;    
$('.data').on('click', function(){
        insertIntoTextArea += $(this).text();
        $("#text-area").val(insertIntoTextArea);
    });
```

Now, you can create the  identifier any way you would like, but I used a class just to make it easier. One thing to remember is it's not usually a good idea to mix JS and PHP together. It just ends up being a mess and you'll run into so many problems. Also, it's not how jQuery is meant to operate.

That said, what I did was create a click [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) that will know that on click, append it to the textarea's value and make sure it is ADDED to the existing data, rather than overwrite what they previously had in the textarea.

Does this help?

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbjr7042/) just in case

Comment: `null + 'something' == 'nullsomething'`. You should initialize your variable to an empty string. `insertIntoTextArea = ''`

Comment: Also, I'd skip `insertIntoTextArea` all together and just use `var $elm = $("#text-area"); $elm.val($elm.val() + $(this).text());`

Answer (score 0):

embeded JS code you write in HTML is really strange, but if you don't want the string to replace each other in `val`, why not add them? for example:

```
// fullname click
var val = $('#text-area').val()
$('text-area').val(val + fullname)
```

All you need to write is about **string process**